# Magento: Order Items on separate rows in Sales Order Grid

Tags: mysql, magento, zend-db, magento-1.6

I am running Magento Community 1.6.2

I am trying to edit my Sales Order Grid so that individual items (that are a part of multiple item orders) appear on their own rows.

The prepareCollection function that I have added to my Grip.php (to have these columns to manipulate in the first place) is as follows:

```
     protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
        ->join(
            'sales/order_item',
            '`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
            array(
                'skus'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.sku SEPARATOR "<br>")'),
                'names' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.name SEPARATOR "<br>")'),
                'quantities' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.qty_ordered SEPARATOR "<br>")'),
                )
            );
            $collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');

        $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

I have added the columns using the following:

```
    $this->addColumn('skus', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('SKUs'),
       'width'     => '120px',
        'index'     => 'skus',
       'type'        => 'text',

      ));


     $this->addColumn('names', array(
       'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Item Names'),
       'width'     => '320px',
       'index'     => 'names',
       'type'        => 'text',
    )); 

      $this->addColumn('quantities', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Quantities'),
        'width'     => '100px',
        'index'     => 'quantities',
        'type'        => 'text',

    ));
```

Currently, in the function, I simply put in a `<br>` to give the appearance of separate lines when viewing the order grid. This is not sufficient for my needs. I plan to utilize the exported CSV from this grid and absolutely must have the itemized order components on separate rows.

Thank you for the assist!

Comment: Have you solved this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know if it's possible to do what your asking for without creating a Mage Sales Order Item Grid.

Here are the lines that worked from the previous post you asked me about... maybe they will help you:

```
$collection->getSelect()->join('catalog_product_index_eav', '`catalog_product_index_eav`.`entity_id` = `main_table`.`product_id` AND `catalog_product_index_eav`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = "brand")', array('attribute_id'));
$collection->getSelect()->join('eav_attribute_option_value', '`eav_attribute_option_value`.`option_id` = `catalog_product_index_eav`.`value`', array('brand' => 'value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the sku array definition instead of creating 'quantities'.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
    ->join(
    'sales/order_item',
    '`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
        array(
            'skus'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat( `sales/order_item`.sku, "(", floor(`sales/order_item`.qty_ordered), ")" SEPARATOR ", ")'),
        ));
```

I believe you can use floor(`sales/order_item`.qty_ordered) to convert to integer your 'quantities' definition as the same.

SKU column on Order Grid results something like:
MBA001(2), MOF004(1)